# Invalid route action [Auth\\SignInController] "UnexpectedValueExpection"

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, vuejs3

I am having a problem with routes. I have created SignIncontroller with the __invoke action and registered its routes on route/api.

My api.php code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    Route::post('signin', 'SignInController');
    Route::post('signout', 'SignOutController');

    Route::get('me', 'MeController');
});
```

I have also created the three routes with __invoke for testing

My SignIncontroller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SignInController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        dd('Sign In');
    }
}
```

If I run on postman I get below error

The error

[image]

Comment: Maybe: `'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth'` ? Because your error says you are just trying to visit Auth\SigninController which doesn't exist in your main directory.

Comment: If i add that it is recognizing the controller, but it returns an empty with below exception. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Try it with: `Route::post('signin', App\Http\Controllers\SignInController::class)` and remove the namespace. Or just use `SignInController::class` and import `use App\Http\Controllers\SignInController` at the top.

Comment: I tried all of that but it is not working! I am new to vue and Laravel

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SignInController;

Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('signin', SignInController::class);
    Route::post('signout', SignOutController::class);
});`